# Por qué mi archivo JSON (WA Stickers) tiene errores y el de otros no?

Tags: android-studio, json

estoy editando con el código brindado por Telegram y todo bien, el problema viene cuando en el archivo contents.json edito evidentemente para meter mis stickers, he tenido varios errores, pero este en específico:

```
Error: sticker width should be 512, sticker pack identifier:1, filename:1.webp/png
```

También tuve otro error en que tenía que poner slash entre las direcciones URL ( \ / \ / )

```
https:\/\/Telegram.org\/privacy
```

He buscado y buscado, y en varias otras apps el contents.json es igual al mío, incluso no tienen esto \ / \ /, la verdad es que no tengo ni idea, cuál es el problema?

Y en el logcat lo único que obtengo es una línea de java, el VALIDATOR para ser específico, pero está claro que mi problema está en el contents.jason, alguien puede ayudarme a dilucidar mi problema por favor?

He validado el JSON, todo OK, ahora estoy poniendo el logcat de AS:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: sticker width should be 512, sticker pack identifier:1, filename:1.webp
        at com.xxx.StickerPackValidator.validateStickerFile(StickerPackValidator.java:139)
        at com.xxx.StickerPackValidator.validateSticker(StickerPackValidator.java:124)
        at com.xxx.StickerPackValidator.verifyStickerPackValidity(StickerPackValidator.java:113)
        at com.xxx.StickerPackLoader.fetchStickerPacks(StickerPackLoader.java:64)
        at com.xxx.EntryActivity$LoadListAsyncTask.doInBackground(EntryActivity.java:90)
        at com.xxx.EntryActivity$LoadListAsyncTask.doInBackground(EntryActivity.java:77)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:255)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
2020-05-23 08:27:43.515 32230-32230/? E/EntryActivity: error fetching sticker packs, sticker width should be 512, sticker pack identifier:1, filename:1.webp
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: No se entiende dónde ocurre tu error. Copia/pega tu json en un validador en línea o ábrelo desde Android Studio, que tiene un validador. Si es otra cosa, pone la traza completa del error. Tu pregunta es poco clara.

Comment: Ya lo hice, disculpa por la falta de data, ojalá puedas ayudarme ahora. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es con tu JSON, sino con tu sticker: su tamaño debe ser 512x512. Eso es que te dicen: pon este `Error: sticker width should be 512` en https://translate.google.es :)

Comment: Pero los stickers casi nunca están en 512x512, la altura efectivamente es 512, pero el ancho no siempre es 512, los packs webp que descargas nunca vienen 512x512, pero ya veo, al parecer es obligatorio que sean de esas dimensiones. Gracias.